# Experience in transforming MIMIC-III dataset to follow EHR standards?

Tags: mimic-iii

I wonder if anyone has attempted to transform MIMIC-III dataset into a format following some EHR standards, such as openEHR or HL7?

If not, any examples of how people use the dataset in non-relational DB fashion?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code/tree/master/buildmimic lists several different distributions of MIMIC: 
apache-drill, docker, hana, monetdb, mysql, oracle, postgres, vagrant.

[Sven Van Poucke](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/8991/sven-van-poucke) worked on integrating the MIMIC-II database in RapidMiner.

I am not aware of conversions to some EHR standards.